# Create a shift in a pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I started to learn how using Pandas in Python. I write a function shift a pandas.Series, this function has to delete the last element and to add the value 0 at the index 0.

```
def create_lagged(row):
   f = row['Net_withdrawal']
   f1 = f.values.np.tolist()
   f1.pop()
   f1.insert(0,0)
   f2 = pd.DataFrame(f1)
   return f2
```

row is DataFrame and 'Net_withdrawal' one of his key. Unfortunately, I have an error message:

> "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" when I use tolist().

Comment: that means you mixed tabs and spaces ... go through your file and change all tabs to spaces ... most ides have this functionality ... it has nothing to do with your actual code ... infact if you copy and paste this back to your source you will find the indentation was corrected by stack overflow to 4 spaces

Comment: as an aside this is built into pandas already ... `my_dataframe.shift(-1,fill_value=0)`

Comment: Thank you Joran Beasley